# Query returning additional empty variable

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I'm running into some weird behaviour when calling values with SQL.

```
$result = mysqli_query($conn,"SELECT DISTINCT value FROM table ORDER BY value ASC");
while($row[] = mysqli_fetch_array($result));
$maxcat = count($row);
```

There are 8 unique values in my table, yet *$maxcat* returns "9". Am I missing something? I'm using the information to populate a list of categories. I knew I'd have to subtract one from maxcat to allow for $row[0], but I'm having to subtract two to make up for this empty value that won't get lost.

```
for ($i=0; $i<=($maxcat-2); $i++)
```

Cheers!

---

Thanks @scrowler & @faintsignal! Using mysqli_num_row() rather than count() is exactly what I needed. Functioning code below.

```
$result = mysqli_query($conn,"SELECT DISTINCT value FROM table ORDER BY value ASC");
$maxcat = mysqli_num_rows($result);
while($row[] = mysqli_fetch_array($result));
```

Comment: Can you dump the table here? We need to see what's inside to reproduce the issue.

Comment: http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.num-rows.php

Comment: "I'm having to subtract two to make up for this empty value that won't get lost." So, is there an empty value / NULL in the data? Could you try "SELECT * from table where value IS NULL or value = '';" ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `while` condition gets evaluated once for every row in your query result, plus one additional time to detect that there are no more rows left. So if you have 8 rows in your result, the `while` condition is evaluated 8 + 1 = **9** times. Hence you add 9 entries to your array `$row`, the final entry having the value `NULL`.

Note, if your `while` loop had a body, that body would only be iterated 8 times because the 9th time the condition would evaluate to `false`.

As @scrowler pointed out, if you just want to count the number of rows in the result, you can simply use `mysqli_num_rows`.

Comment: FYI If you would amend your `while` loop you can populate your array of rows without the extra NULL entry in your array:  `while($temp_row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {  $row[] = $temp_row;  }` (Sorry, multiline code is hard to read inside of comments)